# Java - 100 decimal places in variable

Tags: java, math, double, decimal, pi

I have a problem when it comes to calculating pi with more than 15 decimal places(i used double).

My result looks quite good except my variable is limited to 15 decimal places:

3.140592653839794

Anybody could tell me what i have to do if i want more decimal places?

Thanks and Greeting!

Comment: Use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class in java.

Comment: This is true of 64 bit IEEE floating point numbers in all languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [java.math.BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead of `double` for arbitrary (finite) precision.